# Consider the singularly perturbed cubic equation $\epsilon x^3+x^2-1=0$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Question: "Consider the singularly perturbed cubic equation

$\epsilon x^3+x^2-1=0$

where $\epsilon >0$ is a small parameter. Obtain three-term astymptotic expansions for the two regularly perturbed roots as $\epsilon \to 0$. Use the substitution $x(\epsilon) = \frac{z(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ to obtain the first two terms of an asymptotic approximation of the singulary perturbed solution of this equation as $\epsilon \to 0$."

Look for a solution of the form

$x(\epsilon) = x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2 x_2 +...$

formally sub into equation

$\epsilon(x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2 x_2 +...)^3 + (x_0 + \epsilon x_1 + \epsilon^2 x_2 +...)^2  - 1 = 0$.

Then we have:

$\epsilon(x^3_0+\epsilon(3x^2_0x_1) + \epsilon^2(3x_0x_1^2+3x_0^2x_2)+...)+(x^2_0+\epsilon(2x_0x_1)+\epsilon^2(x_1^2+2x_0x_2)+...)-1=0$.

Comparing coefficients of powers of $\epsilon$:

$O(\epsilon^0) = x^2_0-1=0$

$ \implies x_0=+1,-1$

$O(\epsilon^1) = x^3_0+2x_0x_1=0$

$ \implies $ if $x_0=+1  \space$then $x_1=\frac{-1}{2}$ and if $x_0=-1$ then $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

$O(\epsilon^2) = 3x^2_0x_1+x^2_1+2x_0x_2=0$

$ \implies $ if $x_0=+1 \space$ and $x_1=\frac{-1}{2}$ then $x_2=\frac{5}{8}$ and if  $x_0=-1$ and $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ then $x_2=\frac{-5}{8}$

Giving the final answer of

$x(\epsilon)=1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon + \frac{5}{8}\epsilon^2+...$

and

$x(\epsilon)=-1+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon - \frac{5}{8}\epsilon^2+...$

This is my solution for the first part, I have then gone onto begin the second part of the question by using the substitution and beginning to solve in the same way.

I have plugged in to give me

$\frac{(z(\epsilon))^3}{\epsilon^2} + \frac{(z(\epsilon))^2}{\epsilon} - 1=0$

then subbing in $x(\epsilon) = z(\epsilon)$ gives

$\epsilon(\frac{z(\epsilon)}{\epsilon})^3$ + $(\frac{z(\epsilon)}{\epsilon})^2 - 1 = 0$

simplifying gives

$\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(z(\epsilon))^3$ + $(\frac{z(\epsilon)}{\epsilon})^2 - 1 = 0$

then using $z(\epsilon)=z_0+ \epsilon z + \epsilon z_2 +..$ and subbing into the above equation we have

$\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}(z_0^3+\epsilon(3z^2_0x_1)+\epsilon^2(3z_0z^2_1+3z^2_0z_2)+...) + \frac{1}{\epsilon}(z^2_0+\epsilon(2z_0z_1)+\epsilon^2(z_1^2+2z_0z_2)+...) -1 = 0$

Looking at problems at different powers of $\epsilon$:

$O(\epsilon^0) = 3z_0z^2_1+3z^2_0z_2-1=0$.

The above is what I have so far, which I dont believe is correct.

TIA

Comment: After you have $x_1$ and $x_2$ then $x_3 =-(1/\epsilon+x_1+x_2) = -1/\epsilon + \epsilon + 2\epsilon^3 +O(\epsilon^4).$

Comment: This is very close to [MSE question 2979595](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2979595) "Picking the correct Ansatz for valid solutions in Asymptotic Methods".

Comment: Show us the work  "I have then subbed in for $z(\epsilon)$" and what you did next.

Comment: Edited my solution to give the full one of what i have so far.

Comment: The expansion is $0 = z_0(1+z_0)e^{-2} + z_0z_1(2+3z_0)e^{-1} + O(e^0).$ Now solve for $z_0$ and $z_1$.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3037946).